# TAC of while(1) loop infinite loop

Tags: compiler-construction, while-loop, infinite-loop

How do we write this particular loop in three address code?

```
while(1){
...
}
```

I cannot do this by the normal if-else method of while loop as the condition is not there in the code.

Comment: Hi, have you actually tried to search for possible solutions? Did you find any? Why didn't they suit you?

Answer (score 2):

The three address code(TAC) for the given code would be :-

***CODE :-***

```
while(1){
...
}
```

---

***Three Address Code(TAC) :-***

```
_L0:
_t1=1;
if t1 goto _L0;
```

> Conditional jumps of the form `if x goto L` execute the instruction
>   with Label L next if x is true.